# Issue with minitest in rails using route_translator gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, localization, minitest

I'm experiencing weird behavior in one of my rails projects. The project had no tests yet and i was adding some to begin with. But when i run my tests it seems to run 13 tests without any tests being present in the project.

```
Finished in 0.485554s, 26.7735 runs/s, 2.0595 assertions/s.
13 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 8 errors, 0 skips
```

running the tests verbose i get the name of the tests being run:

```
└─ → rails test -v | grep TestCase
Running via Spring preloader in process 322380
ActionView::TestCase#test_exception_nl_path = 0.00 s = .
ActionView::TestCase#test_exception_path = 0.00 s = .
ActionView::TestCase#test_exception_url = 0.00 s = .
ActionView::TestCase#test_exception_nl_url = 0.00 s = .
ActionMailer::TestCase#test_exception_nl_path = 0.01 s = E
ActionMailer::TestCase#test_exception_nl_path:
ActionMailer::TestCase#test_exception_path = 0.00 s = E
ActionMailer::TestCase#test_exception_path:
ActionMailer::TestCase#test_exception_url = 0.00 s = E
ActionMailer::TestCase#test_exception_url:
ActionMailer::TestCase#test_exception_nl_url = 0.00 s = E
ActionMailer::TestCase#test_exception_nl_url:
ActionController::TestCase#test_exception_path = 0.00 s = E
ActionController::TestCase#test_exception_path:
ActionController::TestCase#test_exception_url = 0.00 s = E
ActionController::TestCase#test_exception_url:
ActionController::TestCase#test_exception_nl_path = 0.00 s = E
ActionController::TestCase#test_exception_nl_path:
ActionController::TestCase#test_exception_nl_url = 0.00 s = E
ActionController::TestCase#test_exception_nl_url:
```

However i cannot find any of those tests in my code base

```
└─ → grep -rni --exclude-dir=log test_exception_nl_path .
//No output
```

When i run the tests i also get these weird errors

```
Error:
ActionMailer::TestCase#test_exception_path:
NoMethodError: undefined method `optimize_routes_generation?' for #<ActionMailer::TestCase:0x000056173140f620>
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:225:in `optimize_routes_generation?'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:196:in `call'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:326:in `block in define_url_helper'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:98:in `block (3 levels) in run'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:195:in `capture_exceptions'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest.rb:272:in `time_it'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:94:in `block in run'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest.rb:367:in `on_signal'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:211:in `with_info_handler'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:93:in `run'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest.rb:1029:in `run_one_method'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:89:in `block (3 levels) in start'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest.rb:367:in `on_signal'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest.rb:354:in `with_info_handler'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/minitest-5.14.1/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
```

In my routes i have some translated routes using the `route_translator` gem

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#home"
  localized do
    ...
    get :thanks, to: "pages#thanks"
    ...
  end

  namespace :admin do
    ...
  end
end
```

and when i remove the `localized` block around the routes the errors go away, and the additional tests that are being run also stop. So my guess is that it has something to do with my configuration of the `localized_routes` gem. But i can't find anything in the documentation or issues on github.

I tried setting up a new rails project with the translated_routes gem to get a minimal reproducible case but in a new rails project it simply works. So i can't reproduce it.

I'm kinda at a loss of where to start looking at what the issue is. So any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that i have a route named `test` in my routes definition.
Renaming my route to `testing` or something fixes the issue.

I created a bug ticket on their repo: https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator/issues/224